# Создание запроса в базу на SQL, без PHP

Tags: mysql, запрос

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать данный код только на SQL, минуя PHP?
В таблице data имеется поле (*email_disp*), которое требуется перенести в другую таблицу (*privacy*). Нюанс в том, что в последней **уже имеется** база пользователей с нужными *id*.
Ответов с INSERT много, но необходимо именно обновить данные, а не создать новые записи.

```
$query = DB::use()->query("SELECT id, email_disp FROM data");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    DB::use()->query('UPDATE privacy SET email_disp = '.$row['email_disp'].' WHERE id = '.$row['id'].');
}
```

Comment: Какая СУБД? MySQL?

Comment: Именно она. 5.7, если это важно (вряд ли)

Comment: REPLACE INTO для принудительной вставки либо замены там где данные уже были.
INSERT..ON DUPLICATE, что тоже самое, но с проверкой на повторы.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Она добавит новые записи и обновит старые

```
INSERT INTO privacy (
  id,
  email_disp
) SELECT
  id,
  email_disp
FROM
  data
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  email_disp = VALUES(email_disp);
```

P.S. Конечно же поле `privacy.id` должно быть первичным или уникальным ключем

Comment: Благодарю, вы сэкономили мне кучу времени